# Need to stop the slider at last image

Tags: jquery, slider

Iam making the image slider all done but cant stop at the last image

Following are the code

```
    var element=$(container);
    element.find('ul').addClass('slides');
    var slides = element.find('ul.slides li');
    var targetSlide=0;
    $.skdslider.currentSlide=0;
    $.skdslider.currentState='pause';

    $.skdslider.createNav(element,slides, config);
    slides.eq(targetSlide).show();
    if (config.autoStart==true){
       $.skdslider.currentState='play'; 
       $.skdslider.interval=setTimeout(function() {
                $.skdslider.playSlide(element,slides, config);
            }, config.delay); 
    }
};
```

Comment: check at last image count and clearTimeout or use jquery stop() to stop the slider.

Comment: Hi Maverickosama92, I am newbie in it...Pls help me...Should I mail u the code. Pls

Comment: yes you could mail me check my profile for email id

Comment: Hi Maverickosama92, cant seems to find your email id. (Sorry mate really new) should I mail you on your facebook page

Comment: Hi Maverickosama92, did u get my mail?

Comment: Thanks a ton Maverickosama92 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add this to your js file (at line 142):

```
if (($.skdslider.currentSlide + 1) == slides.length) {
    clearTimeout($.skdslider.interval);
    return;
}
```

thanks.